# how to acces SerialPort.Flush() and SerialPort.Finalize() functions

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, io

I was just browsing msdn and found this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd169859.aspx).  I did never see the functions `SerialPort.Flush()` or `SerialPort.Finalize()` before. So I tried to use those functions, but I'm getting an error.

I added the `System.IO.Ports` namespace, but I get the following error on the `Finalize()` function:

`Cannot access protected member 'object.~Object()' via a qualifier of type 'System.IO.Ports.SerialPort'; the qualifier must be of type 'STP_Design.SerialCom' (or derived from it)`

and i get the following error on the `Flush()` function:

`'System.IO.Ports.SerialPort' does not contain a definition for 'Flush' and no extension method 'Flush' accepting a first argument of type 'System.IO.Ports.SerialPort' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

I guess I'm accessing the finalizing function with a wrong approach (and I must not access it at all probably) but I'm really wondering what about the `Flush()` function.

I used something like this:

```
    private void test()
    {
        SerialPort s1 = new SerialPort();
        s1.PortName = "COM1";
        s1.Open();
        thread.Sleep(200);
        s1.WriteLine("test");
        s1.Flush();
        s1.Close();
        thread.Sleep(200);
        s1.Finalize();
    }
```

Any insights here?

EDIT: Got the same problem with the SerialPort.Dispose(boolean) function The optional boolean value is not accesseble too...

Comment: You can never call the finalizer directly...

Comment: Also there is no `Flush` method. You can try `SerialPort.BaseStream.Flush` maybe.

Comment: You are looking at the .NET Microframework's documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx : no `Flush`. You are looking at the .Net Micro Framework, which apparently does have a `Flush`

Finalizers are called by GC at the end of garbage collection. They aren't externally accessible by user code, nor should they be explicitly called.

Comment: That seems quite fair... and I figured the Finalize should not be called at all from code, and I figured that the bool in the dispose function is protected. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: MySerial.DiscardInBuffer()

Answer (score -1):

You can use DiscardInBuffer() and DiscardOutBuffer()